# Map JSON to existing pojo object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have recently joined the web services world and have started to work on create and update of hibernate entities using json inputs.

The following api converts a json input to new pojo object:

```
Pojo newObject=mapper.readValue(jsonInput,Pojo.class);
```

This work well with create apis.

Now what about update apis:

I have a big pojo and i don't want to get into long method setting each value into pojo object from json input

i want something like:

```
Pojo existingPojo=getFromDatabase();

existingPojo=mapper.readValue(updateJsonValues,existingPojo);

saveToDatabase(existingPojo);
```

So whatever attributes updateJsonValues has ,they get updated into existingPojo.

This would be great help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use BeanUtils or mapstruct library.

Comment: You can just overwrite your existing POJO with a new POJO and the same id, same outcome

Comment: Agree (with @TA ), overwrite is the way to go. Why do you want to read the existing pojo values from the DB and then update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The story is that this is what `ObjectMapper`-like things inherently do all the time, there is no other way: an object is instantiated first, and then it is updated from the JSON.
The only obstacle is that there is no `readValue()`-like shortcut for it (it could be something like `updateValue()`), so it is a few character longer, you need to use `readerForUpdating()` to get a suitable reader, and then its `readValue()`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Test {
    public String message="Nope";
    public String target="Nope";
    public String toString() {
        return message+" "+target+"!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Test test=new Test();
        System.out.println(test);
        ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.readerForUpdating(test).readValue("{\"message\":\"Hello\"}");
        System.out.println(test);
        mapper.readerForUpdating(test).readValue("{\"target\":\"World\"}");
        System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Nope Nope!
> Hello Nope!
> Hello World!
> ```

---

Edit: if it is needed repeatedly, the reader can be stored and re-used of course:

```
ObjectReader reader=mapper.readerForUpdating(test);
reader.readValue("{\"message\":\"Hello\"}");
System.out.println(test);
reader.readValue("{\"target\":\"World\"}");
System.out.println(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same question and after a lot of digging into the dirt I came across an open source library, [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/). It helps in java beans mapping and generates code for you at the time your application boots up. It worked fine for me. Give it a go.